# Why can't I access inherited protected fields in a derived constructor's member initialization list?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I'm new to OOP. I recently learned some things about Inheritence in C++, and that a `protected` field can't be accessed from outside of the class, but it can be accessed in inherited classes. I have some problems with my code and I don't understand what is wrong:

```cpp
class Base
{
protected:
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
public:
    Base(int a, int b): x(a), y(b) { cout << "Base constructor" << endl; };
    Base(const Base& prev) : x(prev.x), y(prev.y) { cout << "Base copy constructor" << endl; };

    void print_x()
    {
        cout << x << endl;
    }

    void print_y()
    {
        cout << y << endl;
    }

    ~Base() { cout << "Base destructor" << endl; };
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(int a, int b): x(a), y(b) { cout << "Derived constructor" << endl; };    ////////ERROR : Class 
 'Derived' does not have any fields named 'x' and 'y'
};

int main()
{
    Base* b = new Base(10, 20);
    Derived* d = new Derived(10, 20);
    delete b;
    delete d;
    return 0;
}
```

If `Derived` inherits `Base`, why does the compiler say that `Derived` doesn't have the fields `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access them in `Derived`, but they are members of `Base` and cannot be initialized directly in the member initialization list of `Derived`. This also wouldn't work if they were `public`. Note that the `Base` class is initialized before the members of `Derived` are initialized.

To initialize the base, you can call its constructor in the `Derived`'s member initialization list:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
      Derived(int a, int b) : Base(a, b)  {  }; 
};
```

For more details, see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

*PS*: Note that with respect to the member initialization list, there is also no difference to members that are `private` in the base. All members of the base are inherited, and initialized before members of the derived are initialized.

You miss to initialize `z`, and in your example there is no reason to use `new` and `delete`. If you fix the above, you get same output with this code:

```
int main()
{
    Base b(10,20);
    Derived d(10,20);
}
```

Last, but not least, if you plan to use `Derived` polymorphically, you need to declare the destructor of `Base` as `virtual`.

Comment: What do you mean by using it polymorphically?

Comment: @Robert I mean `Base* b = new Derived();` in this case you cannot call `delete b;` without having a virtual destructor in `Base`

Comment: @Robert even if you arent doing it now, sooner or later someone will, so better have a virtual destructor when you inherit publicly

Comment: Oh! I understand.. runtime polymorphism is that?

Comment: @Robert yes that is. If you are not going to use it you could as well inherit privately or use composition